# How to trigger delegate méthodes in helpclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, delegates

Okey folks. This is maybe a bit novice, but I have trouble to figure out how to trigger the NSURLConnection delegates in a helperclass I have.

The question is as follow:

I have a ViewController that will perform a login to a web service. I setup the "connection" object from my view.

In the connection-class I setup a request object (NSMutableURLRequest *request)

Then I setup the connection.

```
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection) {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    dataWebService = [NSMutableData data];
    [connection start];
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
```

The clue is that when I do this in the ViewController-class (place all the delegates) inside my view controller then the delegates automatically triggers and I can login to the web service.

How can I call these delegates from my view controller inside the "connection-class"?

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

I need this because I will use this connection-class to perform other task as well from other views. And it will be a bit overkill to write these delegates in every views I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a method in your connection class like downloadFromURL:sender:, that you could call from any class. When you call it, you provide the URL and supply self as the sender argument. The connection class would have a property, say sendingObject, that you would set to sender:

```
-(void)downloadFromURL:(NSURL *) url sender:(id) sender {
    _receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    sendingObject = sender;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url cachePolicy: NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly timeoutInterval: 30.0];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Implement all the delegate methods in this class, and in the connectionDidFinishLoading: method, you could do something like this:

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [sendingObject performSelector:@selector(resultFromDownloader:) withObject:_receivedData];
}
```

This would allow you to process the data (in resultFromDownloader:) however you need to in any class that calls this method.

Answer (score 0):

You may say it's overkill to put an NSURLConnection and its delegate methods everywhere you need it but it is definitely the cleanest solution.

When using delegates, you should have 1 sender (in this case the NSURLConnection) and 1 receiver (in this case the ViewController). What you want to do is either constantly change that receiver or have multiple receivers, I'm not entirely sure. You can do. If you want to reuse the NSURLConnection (thus keeping 1 receiver) you can simply change its delegate to whichever class needs it at that moment. Which could be difficult to keep track of. If you want to pass the results of just 1 connection to other classes (multiple receivers) you can implement the delegate methods once and use NSNotifications to send the results to every class that's registered as an observer. But notifications cant return values.

Answer (score 0):

How about avoiding the delegates altogether?  In iOS5 or later, you can run the connection and handle the response in a block, like this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        // handle response, data and error here
    }];
```

With this method, you can have one class answer an NSURLConnection and another run it with a block.  Or you can make a class that creates a connection and runs it with a block passed as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I will try different soulutions. But the idea of using blocks sounds like a good way of doing this.